# Highcharts xAxis has extra gap when multiple yAxis

Tags: highcharts

We have a chart that plots multiple series at once.

There are the main y-series (line type) that will have the main data readings. 
There is the option to set two different 'levels' (line types) on the y-axis as well. 
There are also options to have multiple additional y-axis bars (bar types).
With the x-axis being the datetime

Here is what a typical example of a chart looks like with valid date for the given range
[image]

This is working as expected.
We have the main y-series as the average air temp (left y-axis)
Then we have two bars, one for rainfall and one for irrigation (right y-axis)
And then the two 'levels', one red and one blue.

This is all great.
However, when we go to a date range in the future, where there is no air temp data, we get the following
[image]
Note that the start date is 2 days before the date range, and the end date looks equal distance from the end of the 'levels'

Interestingly if we remove the bars we get the following
[image]
This now shows the 'levels' to span the full width of the chart

If we remove the lines and just have the bars then we get the following (which is how it should look, but with the 'levels')
[image]

There seems to be something in here that is causing the conflict when there are multiple y-series without the main y-series.

I am setting the xAxis.setExtremes to the start and end dates of the date range we are looking at, but that seems to be doing nothing.

Here is the config;

```
{
    "chart": {
        "type":"line",
        "animation": {
            "duration":150
        },
        "events":{}
    },
    "credits":{
        "enabled":false
    },
    "title":{
        "text":""
    },
    "subtitle":{
        "text":""
    },
    "tooltip":{
        "shared":true,
        "crosshairs":true,
        "borderWidth":0, 
        "followPointer":true,
        "useHTML":true,
        "headerFormat":"<span style=\"font-size: 10px;\">{point.key}</span><br><br>"
    },
    "xAxis":[
        {
            "id":"x-axis",
            "type":"datetime",
            "crosshair":{
                "snap":false
            },
            "title":{
                "text":"25th Sep 2019 - 1st Oct 2019",
                "margin":15
            }
        }
    ],
    "yAxis":[
        {
            "id":"y-axis-sensors",
            "title":{
                "text":"ºC"
            },
            "reversed":false,
            "visible":true,
            "endOnTick":false,
            "startOnTick":false,
            "alignTicks":false
        },
        {
            "id":"y-axis-moisture",
            "title":{
                "text":"mm"
            },
            "opposite":true,
            "min":0,
            "endOnTick":false,
            "startOnTick":false,
            "alignTicks":false,
            "tickWidth":0,
            "gridLineWidth":0
        }
    ],
    "series":[
        {
            "type":"line",
            "yAxis":"y-axis-sensors",
            "marker":{
                "enabled":false
            },
            "lineWidth":1,
            "animation":false,
            "name":"Full",
            "seriesGroup":"levelSeries",
            "id":"series-level-range-full",
            "color":"#31B5E0",
            "showInLegend":false,
            "states":{
                "hover":{
                    "enabled":false
                }
            },
            "enableMouseTracking":false,
            "zIndex":5,
            "step":true,
            "data":[
                [1569369600000,5],
                [1569974400000,5]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type":"line",
            "yAxis":"y-axis-sensors",
            "marker":{
                "enabled":false
            },
            "lineWidth":1,
            "animation":false,
            "name":"Refill",
            "seriesGroup":"levelSeries",
            "id":"series-level-range-refill",
            "color":"#D23333",
            "showInLegend":false,
            "states":{
                "hover":{
                    "enabled":false
                }
            },
            "enableMouseTracking":false,
            "zIndex":5,
            "step":true,
            "data":[
                [1569369600000,17],
                [1569974400000,17]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type":"column",
            "yAxis":"y-axis-moisture",
            "marker":{
                "enabled":false
            },
            "name":"Rainfall",
            "seriesGroup":"rainfallSeries",
            "states":{
                "hover":{
                    "enabled":false
                }
            },
            "id":"series-rainfall",
            "pointWidth":6,
            "borderWidth":0,
            "color":"rgba(41, 182, 246, 0.3)",
            "data":[
                [1569488400000,5]
            ],
            "zIndex":10,
            "stacking":"normal",
            "stack":"moisture"
        },
        {
            "type":"column",
            "yAxis":"y-axis-moisture",
            "marker":{
                "enabled":false
            },
            "states":{
                "hover":{
                    "enabled":false
                }
            },
            "name":"Irrigation",
            "seriesGroup":"irrigationSeries",
            "id":"series-irrigation",
            "pointWidth":6,
            "borderWidth":0,
            "color":"rgba(205,220,57, 0.3)",
            "data":[[1569574800000,3]],
            "zIndex":10,
            "stacking":"normal",
            "stack":"moisture"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am at a bit of a loss here as to why this is happening.
Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions can be to add additional x-axis and bind line series to it. Then it looks like your expected result. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "type": "line",
    "animation": {
      "duration": 150
    },
    "events": {}
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "shared": true,
    "crosshairs": true,
    "borderWidth": 0,
    "followPointer": true,
    "useHTML": true,
    "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-size: 10px;\">{point.key}</span><br><br>"
  },
  "xAxis": [{
    "id": "x-axis1",
    "type": "datetime",
    "crosshair": {
      "snap": false
    },
    "title": {
      "text": "25th Sep 2019 - 1st Oct 2019",
      "margin": 15
    }
  }, {
   "id": "x-axis2",
    visible: false,
    "type": "datetime"
  }],
  "yAxis": [{
      "id": "y-axis-sensors",
      "title": {
        "text": "ºC"
      },
      "reversed": false,
      "visible": true,
      "endOnTick": false,
      "startOnTick": false,
      "alignTicks": false
    },
    {
      "id": "y-axis-moisture",
      "title": {
        "text": "mm"
      },
      "opposite": true,
      "min": 0,
      "endOnTick": false,
      "startOnTick": false,
      "alignTicks": false,
      "tickWidth": 0,
      "gridLineWidth": 0
    }
  ],
  "series": [
   {
      "type": "line",
      xAxis: 'x-axis2',
      "yAxis": "y-axis-sensors",
      "marker": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "lineWidth": 1,
      "animation": false,
      "name": "Full",
      "seriesGroup": "levelSeries",
      "id": "series-level-range-full",
      "color": "#31B5E0",
      "showInLegend": false,
      "states": {
        "hover": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "enableMouseTracking": false,
      "zIndex": 5,
      "step": true,
      "data": [
        [1569369600000, 5],
        [1569974400000, 5]
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "line",
      xAxis: 'x-axis2',
      "yAxis": "y-axis-sensors",
      "marker": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "lineWidth": 1,
      "animation": false,
      "name": "Refill",
      "seriesGroup": "levelSeries",
      "id": "series-level-range-refill",
      "color": "#D23333",
      "showInLegend": false,
      "states": {
        "hover": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "enableMouseTracking": false,
      "zIndex": 5,
      "step": true,
      "data": [
        [1569369600000, 17],
        [1569974400000, 17]
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "column",
      xAxis: 'x-axis1',
      "yAxis": "y-axis-moisture",
      "marker": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "name": "Rainfall",
      "seriesGroup": "rainfallSeries",
      "states": {
        "hover": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "id": "series-rainfall",
      "pointWidth": 6,
      "borderWidth": 0,
      "color": "rgba(41, 182, 246, 0.3)",
      "data": [
        [1569488400000, 5]
      ],
      "zIndex": 10,
      "stacking": "normal",
      "stack": "moisture"
    },
    {
      "type": "column",
      xAxis: 'x-axis1',
      "yAxis": "y-axis-moisture",
      "marker": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "states": {
        "hover": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "name": "Irrigation",
      "seriesGroup": "irrigationSeries",
      "id": "series-irrigation",
      "pointWidth": 6,
      "borderWidth": 0,
      "color": "rgba(205,220,57, 0.3)",
      "data": [
        [1569574800000, 3]
      ],
      "zIndex": 10,
      "stacking": "normal",
      "stack": "moisture"
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/juwc8f37/

Comment: Hi Wojciech, I just saw this come in, thank you for your response, I shall give that ago

Comment: You're welcome. If you find this answer helpful please upvote or mark it as a correct one, thanks.